# ASP.NET webform Fileupload inside an ascx which is inside an updatepanel in the aspx

Tags: asp.net, webforms

here is some code in my page :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelEQSelector" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <uc12:EQSelector ID="custEQSelector" OnEqChange="custEQSelector_OnEqChange" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Inside my user Control, I'm asked to add a fileuploader.
After coding it simply, I tested and my fileuploader is always empty.
I've searched a while and discovered that it was a normal behavior.
The solution to make it work is to add a `PostBackTrigger` for the updatePanel.

When I tested it in my aspx page, I achieved to do it and my fileUploader had the file.
Then I tried to add it dynamically (to finally do it in my control), it worked  with that :

```
PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = this.btnTest.ID;
        this._UpdatePanelEQSelector.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

But I can't manage to make this code work in my control (I passed my updatePanel as a parameter to my control set in Load, the fileUpload is always empty)

Do you see a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does it postback, but leaves the control empty? or is it not posting back at all. If it's not posting back at all I'd add this

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnTest);
```

to the page_load of the user control.

If it is posting back, but the control is empty, then I'd wager there is probably some dodgy html somewhere on the page and the values are getting lost.

Comment: Yes, it does Postback. For now, I have put my updatePanel inside my ascx and added my PostBackTrigger inside the ascx. It looks like there are no effects on the existing application behavior... Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Ah ok, in which case, this would have fixed your issue: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29004-A-control-with-ID-button-could-not-be-found.aspx